# Is it possible to output the result of a union of two subqueries in alternating order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, window-functions

Lets say I have two subqueries in a UNION statement like so:

```
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM users
    ORDER BY registration_date
) 
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT *
    FROM food
    ORDER BY popularity
)
```

The output is the following:

```
Bob
Alice
Steve
Mark
...
Sandwich
Pizza
Burger
Fries
...
```

Is it possible to output them in an alternating fashion, such that the output is:

```
Bob
Sandwich
Alice
Pizza
Steve
Burger
Mark
Fries
...
```

Each query output is thousands of items.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number()` if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
(select name, 1 src, row_number() over(order by registration_date) rn from users)
union all 
(select name, 2, row_number() over(order by popularity) from food)
order by rn, src
```

In each `union`ed subquery, we use `row_number()` to rank the records, and add another column, called `src` to identify from which table the record comes from.

Then all that is left to do is `order by` the assigned `row_number()`, using the additional column to alternate the records.

Note that I modified your query to enumerate the columns being `select`ed in the subqueries; `select *` is generally not a good practice, especially with `union all`, which requires both datasets to have the same number of columns (with equivalent datatypes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately using Mysql 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are not using MySQL 8+, you can still simulate `ROW_NUMBER` using a correlated count query:

```
(
    SELECT 1 AS idx, name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u2 WHERE u2.registration_date < u1.registration_date) rn
    FROM users u1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 2, name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM food f2 WHERE f2.popularity < f1.popularity) rn
    FROM food f1
)
ORDER BY
    rn,
    idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id :=0;

SELECT id,t.* FROM(
SELECT  u.*,(@id:=@id+1) AS id

   FROM users u
    ORDER BY registration_date
) 
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT f.*,(@id:=@id+2) AS id

    FROM food f 
    ORDER BY popularity
)t
ORDER BY id;
```